# Restrict parameter string to an array of strings at compile-time

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a method with a parameter as a string data-type. I there a convenient way that I can limit the strings the function will accept for the said parameter?

It is my intention that my Visual Studio code editor will underline the invalid string parameter from the function call (just like it would if you defined an expected object or Boolean parameter as a string).

```
Public Sub SomeSub(someParameter As String)
    ' Some action.
End Sub

Public Sub AnotherSub()
    ' Accept only these strings.
    SomeSub("The capital of France is Paris.")
    SomeSub("The capital of England is London.")
    SomeSub("The capital of Italy is Rome.")
    ' The following string shouldn't be accepted.
    ' i.e. String is underlined with an error.
    SomeSub("I like turtles.")
End Sub
```

I've researched arrays but they're generally performed from the point the function is being called or after the parameter has been passed, neither of which will suffice as they only allow me to indicate an incorrect parameter to user which is pointless. Considering I'm trying to inform the coder, I need the coder's error to be underlined as the coder finishes typing it.

I'd like to know if there's a direct and convenient means of achieving this without something as complex as a separate function or an additional dozen lines of code.

Comment: There's no way to enforce this behavior at compile-time.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for the definite confirmation. I'm not certain what the SO policy on "there is no answer" as an answer. If permissible, you may as well submit your comment as an answer to allow my question to reach a point of closure. I've added "compile-time" to the question title for better context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there's no way to enforce such behavior with strings at compile-time.